# ユーザープロパティーを取得できない

Tags: monaca, angularjs

```
monaca.cloud.User.getProperty("age")
    .done(function(age) {
        console.log(age);
        var user = age; 
    }).fail(function() {
       console.log("get failed") 
    });
```

このAPIを用いて取得した値を、AngularJSの`$scope`で用いたいのですがどのようにすればよいですか？